# In PHP session values get vanishing

Tags: php, session

In My code when I do login I am setting session values, in my config file,
after that if I visit at any other page my session get vanished. A very strange situation, because I run same code in my lots of projects.

Please help me.

In top of the config I use session_start();

Comment: can you post how you set and get them?

Comment: The other page you go to, is it within the same domain (and not a sub-domain)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to include

```
session_start();
```

**At the top** of **every page** in which you use session variables. It's not enough to call it on one single page or calling it after you try using the session variables.

Answer (score 0):

You have certain that you are run `session_start()`?

Try run:

```
var_dump(session_id());
```

If an empty string is returned, your `session_start()` don't be run. You can try:

```
@session_start();
```

Or do

```
session_commit();
```

On end of script.

Answer (score 0):

try this [PHP Session Variables](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Check session.save_path in your php.ini. Do you see session files in that folder? Is it writable for PHP interpreter? Does your disk have enough free space for your session file?

Answer (score 0):

When i met that kind of problem, i'll try to create a simple script just to check if the session is saved or not, if the session is not saved even for the simplest script, then i'll contact my hosting provider to check on my session save handler. A good hosting provider will likely check you your session save handler, and change the configuration as needed